# How to add an "else" option after a list of "if" commands in python

Tags: python, if-statement

There is a bank app and you have to log in, and certain codes have certain users. how would i make it to where if none of the codes were used, i can have a message saying no valid code was entered?

```
#login id 10
account_name1 = "Mark"
account_balance1 = "150"

#login id 11
account_name2 = "John"
account_balance2 = "190"

#login id 12
account_name3 = "Bob"
account_balance3 = "210"

login_id = input("What is your login id?")

if login_id == "10":
    print("Hello, %s, your balance is $%s." % (account_name1, account_balance1))


if login_id == "11":
    print("Hello, %s, your balance is $%s." % (account_name2, account_balance2))


if login_id == "12":
    print("Hello, %s, your balance is $%s." % (account_name3, account_balance3))

#then here i would have code making it to where if something except 10,11,12 was entered, it would give a message
```

Comment: I think it would be best to redesign the way you check for login_id as this is not optimal.

Comment: Seems to be a very basic example of discrete cases (login_id can only equal one of the options), meaning you should be fine using basic if / elif statements (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) - unless I'm misunderstanding your intension.

Comment: Just chain your `if` statements as `elif` (else if) and add an `else` in the end. Given that `login_id` can only have one value you don't need to separate the statements.

Comment: Alternatively: `if login_in not in ["10", "11", "12"]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the account data into a dictionary using the id as keys. If an id exist you can print out the hello message using the corresponding account data, otherwise print an error message:

```
accounts = {
    "10": {
        "name": "Mark",
        "balance": "150",
    },
    "11": {
        "name": "John",
        "balance": "190",
    },
    "12": {
        "name": "Bob",
        "balance": "210",    
    }
}

login_id = input("What is your login id?")

try:
    print(f"Hello, {accounts[login_id]['name']}, your balance is {accounts[login_id]['balance']}")
except KeyError:
    print("No valid code entered!")
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need to be doing in this case is a string of "else if"s, rather than just "if".

This exists in many languages. An "else if" comes after an if, and it's purpose is to say "if the PREVIOUS if did NOT evaluate to true and the CURRENT if DOES..."

At the end of all this, you put an "else", meaning "If non of the previously-chained if statements evaluated".

In Python this is done with the "elif" and "else" keywords.

```py
if login_id == "10":
    print("Hello, %s, your balance is $%s." % (account_name1, account_balance1))


elif login_id == "11":
    print("Hello, %s, your balance is $%s." % (account_name2, account_balance2))


elif login_id == "12":
    print("Hello, %s, your balance is $%s." % (account_name3, account_balance3))

else:
    #YOUR CODE HERE
```

Comment: though this answers the question quite literally, @finswimmer's solution is more pythonic